# Email forwarding - iOS

Tags: ios, email, attachments

Someone sent me an email with an image attached. I want to review the image and forward it to someone else.
How do I do that?

Comment: I want to download the image then resize it and send it to someone else.

Comment: so what is holding you back in downloading then resizing then attaching to new email ?

Answer (score 1):

Using the application Mail click on your mail. Then click in the bottom bar the **4th icon that is an arrow**. Press **Forward**. If it asks if you want to include attachments from original message, press **Include**. Then just fill the information depending on who do you want to send it to.